# Is it possible to create multi-tiered WHERE statements in mySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm currently developing a program that will generate reports based upon lead data. My issue is that I'm running 3 queries for something that I would like to only have to run one query for. For instance, I want to gather data for leads generated in the past day 
`submission_date > (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)` 
and I would like to find out how many total leads there were, and how many sold leads there were in that timeframe. (sold=1 / sold=0). The issue comes with the fact that this query is currently being done with 2 queries, one with `WHERE`sold`= 1` and one with `WHERE`sold`= 0`. This is all well and good, but when I want to generate this data for the past day,week,month,year,and all time I will have to run 10 queries to obtain this data. I feel like there HAS to be a more efficient way of doing this. I know I can create a mySQL function for this, but I don't see how this could solve the problem.
Thanks!!

Comment: WHERE date > xyz AND sold = 1 ?

Comment: I know how to use AND and OR statements. I guess I'm wondering if there is a way to group where statements to return multiple result sets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do is to exploit the aggregate functions (usually `SUM` and `COUNT` help you the most in this situation) along with MySQL's `IF()` function.

For example, you could use a query such as:

```
SELECT 
  SUM(IF(sold = 1, sold, 0)) AS TotalSold, 
  SUM(IF(sold = 0, sold, 0)) AS TotalUnsold,
  SUM(IF(submission_date > (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK) 
    AND sold = 1, sold, 0) AS TotalSoldThisWeek
FROM ...
WHERE ...
```

The condition (e.g. `sold = 1`) could be as complex as you want by using `AND` and `OR`.

*Disclamer: code wasn't tested, this was just provided as an example that should work with minor modifications.*

Comment: Awesome, I like that alternative better, and it should be applicable using submission_date > (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY too

Comment: Thanks so much for all your help, made my life a LOT easier :)

Answer (score 2):

Why not GROUP BY sold so you get the totals for sold and not sold

Comment: Awesome, that will solve the issue of sold vs not sold. Any way to do this for day,week,month,year?

Comment: @Brendan: it might not be more efficient than separate queries, but you could create a temp table (call it 'cutoff_times') with the 5 cutoff values, and then do `main_table AS m JOIN cutoff_times AS t ON m.submission_date > t.cutoff_date`.  This is a 'greater-than join' rather than the usual equi-join.